# When is reputation lost without any indication in user profile?

Tags: discussion, reputation, lost-reputation

A few hours ago, I had 418 reputation on StackOverflow. Currently, my profile shows 371 reputation, meaning I lost 47 reputation (I don't mind it).

Surprisingly, there are no notifications in my profile like "User was removed" or anything at all.

I got no downvotes in the last couple of hours. No questions or answers were deleted. My profile is as it was before. What might be the reason?

Comment: there is a tick mark at reputation tab's bottom '"show removed posts" just tick it to know more

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question of yours:

[Conditional operators in Java throw an unexpected NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937410/conditional-operators-in-java-throw-an-unexpected-nullpointerexception)

was deleted 3 hours ago, after having been closed as a duplicate of: [NullPointerException through auto-boxing-behavior of Java ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763983/nullpointerexception-through-auto-boxing-behavior-of-java-ternary-operator)

It had 9 upvotes and two downvotes, which explains a good part of that reputation change. Make sure you tick the "show removed posts" in your profile reputation display, and expand everything if you want to try and track down every last removed post to find the other missing rep.

Comment: Nice, how did you find it?

Comment: 10k tools menu, "deleted" tab, checked the first few recently deleted questions that looked like Java.

Comment: Neat, I knew there is some use for that tab.. ;)

Comment: Yeah, that's not the best-designed part of the site, but still useful from time to time.